# UTF8 with php pear DB package not working

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, pear

I am storing some russian characters into my database. Data is saving correctly. For that I have changed the collation of field from ascii to utf8_general_ci. So the data is saving correctly.

I am using php data object to get the data.But the characters are displaying as ??? .  I tried with `set names utf8` but no luck . If use normal mysql query it is returning the correct characters. Is there any other way to make it working in Pear object

This is code which I am using

```
    $obj = DB_DataObject::Factory('table');
    $obj->exec("set names utf8");       
    $obj->query("(SELECT * FROM table");
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from querying your data correctly, you also need to set the output encoding in your HTML correctly.

Use any of these:

- charset attribute in content-type http header
- meta charset tag
- xml encoding attribute

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML) for more information.

---

In our `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, we also have:

```
collation_server=utf8_general_ci
character_set_server=utf8

skip-character-set-client-handshake
character-set-client = utf8

init_connect    = 'SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci'
init_connect    = 'SET NAMES utf8'
```

It might be that the `character-set-client` setting helps.

Comment: do I need to add it code ? because I have already added in the html <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en" xmlns:fb="ogp.me/ns/fb#">; <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> thats why normal mysql query is displaying the russian characters.

Comment: tried your solution . After that I am getting some other characters on screen "u0420u0430u0437u043cu0435u0440" is there any other settings? thanks

Comment: there is something else broken. try a simple `var_dump($row->columnname);die();` what do you get?

Comment: great man Actually it returning the correct format. But after data is fetched it is conver it to json format . There the things are going wrong